# Getting data out of a simpleXML array

Tags: php, simplexml

To the esteemed readers

I'm trying to retrieve data from an xml array of data taken from pubmed. The array looks like this:

```
<summa>
    <DocS>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Item Name="PubDate" Type="Date">1999</Item>
        <Item Name="EPubDate" Type="Date"/>    //<- notice the open tag
        <Item Name="Source" Type="String">source a</Item>
        <Item Name="AuthorList" Type="List">
            <Item Name="Author" Type="String">a</Item>
            <Item Name="Author" Type="String">b</Item>
        </Item>
    </DocS>
    <DocS>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Item Name="PubDate" Type="Date">1781</Item>
        <Item Name="EPubDate" Type="Date"/></Item> //<- notice the closed tag
        <Item Name="Source" Type="String">source a</Item>
        <Item Name="AuthorList" Type="List">
            <Item Name="Author" Type="String">a</Item>
            <Item Name="Author" Type="String">b</Item>
            <Item Name="Author" Type="String">c</Item>
            <Item Name="Author" Type="String">d</Item>
        </Item>
    </DocS>
</summa>
```

The array is variably long but will always have the initial structure like this :

```
<summa>
    <DocS>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Item Name="PubDate" Type="Date">1999</Item>
```

The data that I specifically need is this

```
<Item Name="PubDate" Type="Date">data needed </Item>"
```

The code below is what I'm trying and it doesn't work. Can anybody help me?

```
$pmid_all=file_get_contents($url_id);

$p=simplexml_load_string($pmid_all);

$result = $p->xpath('/item');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo 'item: ',$node,"\n";
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" as in: "no results" from the xpath query? An error? Try to be more precise please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're querying for item elements at the root level (`/item`). Try replacing your xpath query with `/summa/docs/item`.

Edit: Your XML is also malformed
`<Item Name="EPubDate" Type="Date"/></Item>`

Either remove the `/` or the `</Item>`.

After fixing that, this worked for me:

```
$pmid_all=file_get_contents("foo.xml");
$p=simplexml_load_string($pmid_all);
$result = $p->xpath('/summa/DocS/Item');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo 'item: ',$node,"\n";
}
```

In answer to your comment below this: To grab the first `Item`-Element in each `DocS`-Element:

```
$pmid_all=file_get_contents("foo.xml");

$p=simplexml_load_string($pmid_all);
$result = $p->xpath('/summa/DocS');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    $items = $node->xpath("Item");
    echo 'item: ',$items[0],"\n"; // $item[0] is the first Item found, $item[1] the 2nd, etc...
}
```

Comment: +1 Indeed as @ccKep says, you need to provide the full path to the item unless you are iterating through and the pointer is at that level.

Comment: Awesome! Got the XML cleaned up. I am now returning all `<item>`. If I  only want to get the first `<item>` in each `<docs>` how would that be done?

Comment: Just look through `/summa/DocS` and grab the Item element without a loop. Will Edit/Append this Answer if you want a complete example. Edit: Edited answer with full example.

Comment: Perfect. Did have to change `$items` to `$item`, though   :)

Answer (score 0):

Your XML need to be cleaned first. Somme tags are closed twice, some never closed... You won't be abble to parse this kind of malformed XML.